# Arduino Negative Voltage Reading with Positive Ground

Tags: arduino, batteries, sensor, solar-cell

I am trying to measure voltage & current off a solar charge controller from panel, battery & load simultaneously with my arduino. I have managed to achieve this by tying all the negatives together and using it as GND, however, when I do that the charge controller doesn't function properly and when I switch to off-mode the loads still run. After checking the instruction manual further, I found out that the positives are shared common between Pan, Bat, Load. This was confirmed with a multimeter.

So now what I am thinking of doing is using the positive from the battery as the GND reference and then measuring all other voltages (through voltage dividers with respect to the GND). The voltages should then range between -17V to 0V.

However, I have read that the analog input pins are not able to read negative voltages, and with respect to the positive GND, the Analog inputs will all be negative.

EDIT: I was thinking of using an amplifier to invert positive ground to a negative ground, meaning I could measure all the positive sides of the voltages. But after getting answers from you guys it seems I may not have to use an amplifier and a voltage divider may suffice. I have currently included a 2 resistor voltage divider between each analog input, +5V source, Vmeasure which you can see in the diagram below.

According to my calculations, if this works, @-17V I should see 0.6V @ analog input. @0V I should see 4V at analog input.

I'd appreciate feedback on this circuit, and below in the second image I've also included a piece of another method suggested by @jonk (thanks), and would be interested in knowing what the benefits are of method B) over method A)

Thanks!

Ps. the ameters are there in place of ACS712 current sensors which also go into analog input pins.

Method A)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2Hqwe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Method B (EDIT: This method has worked, I am still yet to test method A) thanks @Jonk))

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsfWlg.png)</sup>

Comment: I think the schematic is missing?

Comment: @jonk it looks like it's there for me. Can you see it now? If not, I'll just throw in a screenshot :)

Comment: Are those resistors _your_ attempt at providing a voltage divider for your analog inputs? Or are they required by your charge controller for some odd reason?

Comment: Also, is -12 V the largest value you need to measure? Or can that voltage be even more negative?

Comment: My attempt at providing a voltage divider. The voltage drop across each of the 2 resistors should be the same as the voltage of panel, load, battery respectively - so i used the divider to get the voltage down to something the arduino could input.

Comment: I'd suspect up to -17V max from the panel. about -14 from battery & load. Thanks!

Comment: Can you afford to draw a bit of current from the load, or do you need a high-Z (DMM-like) input here?

Comment: Can afford to draw current, need to get it out ASAP. So anything that can get the job done. And then will optimise afterwards :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want measure input voltages that may be both negative and positive, using an Arduino ADC where the analog input pins can't read negative voltages, then you might consider the following style of three-resistor divider shown on the left side (the right side we will get towards):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbEBR4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The \$V_i\$ terminal goes to what you want to measure and the \$V_o\$ pin goes to your ADC input (or to a buffer amplifier, if you prefer.)

Your Arduino ADC needs to see an input impedance that is less than \$10\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$, total. With the above divider arrangement, this is \$R_{IN}=R_i+R_p\vert\vert R_g\$. Roughly speaking, since \$R_p\$ or \$R_g\$ will be larger than \$R_p\vert\vert R_g\$, we just need to make \$R_i+R_p\lt 10\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$.

But taking into account your worst case \$V_i=-17\:\textrm{V}\$ and power supply of \$V_{CC}=5\:\textrm{V}\$, it must also be the case that \$R_p \lt \tfrac{5}{17} R_i\$. Another consideration that comes from a separate equation solving for \$R_g\$ suggests that \$R_p \lt \tfrac{2}{9} R_i\$. So \$R_i \lt \tfrac{10\:\textrm{k}\Omega}{1+\tfrac{2}{9}}\$. So that is our more important constraint. \$R_i \le 8.2\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$. That's a standard value of \$R_i =8.2\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ and I then just picked \$R_p=1.8\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ as an appropriate standard value, as well.

From this, you can compute \$R_g=V_o\frac{R_i R_p}{\left(V_{CC}-V_o\right) R_i - \left(17+V_o\right) R_p}\$, where you get to pick \$V_o\$ when \$V_i=-17\:\textrm{V}\$. It's not linear, though. Looking at the curve, I think \$R_g=2.7\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ looks good.

The input impedance is now \$9.3\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$, which meets the needed criteria for the ADC. And at \$V_i=-17\:\textrm{V}\$ you will get \$V_o=670\:\textrm{mV}\$ and at \$V_i=-10\:\textrm{V}\$ you will get \$V_o=1490\:\textrm{mV}\$ and at \$V_i=0\:\textrm{V}\$ you will get \$V_o=2650\:\textrm{mV}\$.

In the above case, I'm assuming you can share grounds, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jonk That all makes sense regarding impedance and how to calculate correct resistor values. I'll test on my Arduino shortly - just wanted to confirm first though, what is the purpose of the resistor Rg between common positive -> v0? Could this voltage divider be achieved with just Ri & Rp? Also the +5V that is being provided by the Arduino, is it provided with reference to the arduino GND? So if we put lets say +12 on the Arduino GND, the Arduino can still supply +5V with reference to the GND (and not actually -7V) am I correct? Thanks mate!

Comment: @KenH \$R_g\$ and \$R_p\$ make up a resistor divider, dividing down the Arduino power supply's +5 V to something else -- +3 V. But this now has a Thevenin resistance of about \$1.1\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$, against which \$R_i\$ works. I'm assuming that you will set the Arduino common to the charge controller common, but that you will NOT connect any other part of the power supplies together. DO NOT put +12 onto the Arduino ground. That's not the purpose here!!

Comment: first of all, thanks a lot for your time mate! I've posted a couple of edits on my question to make what I'm thinking about a bit more clear. Please see the diagrams. Firstly, I am wondering whether or not the voltage divider of the first circuit will work, without the Rg? Secondly, in response to your +12V warning, I was planning on connecting the charge controller common (which is ~ +12 relative to the negative side). However I think it was a terminology issue on my behalf, so is it safe for me to connect the positive charge controller common into GND? Thanks!

Comment: @KenH I gather you are using a +9 VDC mains-powered unit to supply power to the Arduino's voltage regulators, which can then provide +5 V to operate the Arduino. And that you then have access to tap into the +5 V supply rail of the Arduino for the resistor dividers. Is that correct? (Or is that +9 V battery I see there an accident?)

Comment: You are correct @jonk I am using a 9VDC supply. I would ideally like to power the arduino with the battery (from charge controller) via a buck converter. But I figured there would be issues in using it as a power supply and also GND. Am I correct? Or do you also know a way around this?

Comment: @KenH It's hard to know what's best without a more detail. For now, let's just focus on this and see how it comes out. Given what you said, yes, I think this will create readable voltages given your last schematic. Before you actually connect up the ADC input wire... do put a voltmeter from the shared ground (use the [-] lead there) to the point where all three resistors join (use the [+] lead here) and see what value you get there. DO NOT wire up the ADC input to that point until AFTER you check it with a voltmeter. Just to be safe. It should read a positive value, if wired the way I said.

Comment: thanks so much for helping out. I'm now measuring voltage and current & charge controller is working fine, all panel, bat, load measurements working fine. Thanks! One last question if you might know - is there any way I can also power the arduino from the same battery that's being measured in the circuit we discussed / created. - Also I've created an excel table to help me choose resistance values that maximise the voltage range, while keeping impedance below 10kohm. I've chosen 2.2k for Rp, 8.2k & 8.2k for Rg & Ri. Which keeps impedance just below 10k and increases range from 2V -> 3V.

Comment: @KenH Thanks about taking the time to let me know it's okay, as first discussed. As far as simply powering the Arduino? Can it take accepting a 12 V source, directly into the Vcc input? How much does that supply vary? Can it ever exceed the Vcc input specs?

Comment: the bat voltage will vary from 12-14V, is it fine for me to use a buck converter and then put the positive output to Arduino Vin & negative into Arduino Gnd and then still put in the entire + common of charge controller to GND? Also, unfortunately I am now having circuit issues. It's night here and when the panel is placed facedown, with no arduino connected it measures around 0.4V across the terminals with multimeter (fine). When arduino is connected, it's measuring about -2V. So the +5V ref voltage seems to have an influence on Vpanel even when panel is facedown. Will research more!

Comment: @KenH Yes, a buck might be reasonable to use. Worth testing it. Sorry to hear about the new issues! At least the input resistor, \$R_i\$, can provide some protection of your Arduino input pin!! That's a good side effect. Looking forward to new info.

Comment: I've adjusted the circuit as per the schematic B in my OP. Because I was picking up a positive voltage at Vx of about +2V (ie. Vpanel was -2V), I figured some voltage from Vy was dropping across R3 and resulting in the unwanted positive voltage at Vx. So according to my understanding if we could reduce i2, we could reduce the voltage Vx. After replacing your 2.7k resistor with a 68ohm resistor (allowing more current to flow to ground but reducing arduino A1 input resolution to 0.13V). Vx stays in the negative ie. Vpanel stays positive (what we want).

Comment: Ps. @jonk, previous comment is regarding when panel is off. Further to that, I think if I can block i2 from going through when Vx = 0. ie in you resistor setup if Vy > 2.65V then I can limit the Vx to the range -17 -> 0. And not have Vx go to the positive. I am looking up use of zener diodes to help me achieve this, any advice will be appreciated - will contribute when I've got a solution!