# How do I convert a +10v to -10v single input to dual 0-5v outputs?

Tags: arduino, voltage

I am currently trying to interface a input voltage with an Arduino that reads between +10v and -10v after it has been brought down to appropriate levels. The original use of this voltage drives a motor forward or backward based on the bias of the voltage.

My current idea to interface with the Arduino is to use a voltage divider to lower the voltage to the 5v range, and then to split the positive and negative voltages to separate analog input pins.

I have successfully pulled down the voltage to +5v to -5v, but I am struggling to convert the -0.01v to -5 to its own 0-5v analog input for the Arduino.

Does anyone have an idea on where to go with this? Or a better idea on where to start?

Comment: Using two op-amps, ideal rectifier.

Answer (score 3):

You can attenuate the input to +/-2 volts with a resistor voltage divider then add an offset of 2.5 volts (via an op-amp or a more sophisticated voltage divider) to get a range from 0.5 volts to 4.5 volts. Feed this into your analogue input and now you have -10 volts remapped to 0.5 volts and +10 volts remapped to 4.5 volts (leaving a bit of headroom either side).

Comment: Why do you mention a op-amp ? All that is needed is three resistors. See the calculation by 'jonk' in his answer here : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266786/arduino-negative-voltage-reading-with-positive-ground In my opinion the dual 0-5V is not needed if it can be done with with a single 0-5V output.

Comment: @Jot Sure, three resistors is optimum/minimum but some folk may include an op-amp as a buffer and sometimes an op-amp is used to provide hard signal limiting to the ADC's supply rails to prevent ADC damage should the input voltage (-10V to +10V) become excessively large. My answer also suggests using a single input and not two inputs.

Comment: What I am trying to do is control a arm that drives to the left when the voltage is positive, and right when the voltage is negative. I need it to be able to move smoothly as the voltage increases, or goes negative, which is why I think having a dual input would work best.  What I am working on is a slipball assembly for a level c full flight simulator. Right now I have it set up to drive when I set the pin voltage via code, but I am designing a pcb that will connect to the input. Any kind of circuitry that could do what I need can be used, I'm just at a loss on how to split the voltage up.

Comment: I don't think having two inputs would work well at all. For instance, if you have slight discrepencies between the two inputs and one is producing a non-zero digital value when it should be zero, how do you deal with that. ADCs are not perfect and just because you feed 0 volts to its input it doesn't mean you get binary zero as the result so, how do you deal with this?

Comment: Andy, that is exactly why I asked, this is a problem I hadn't thought of yet. I suppose I need to come up with a way to invert the input only when it goes negative.

Comment: No, just use a single input as I propose and don't worry about ambiguities.

Comment: @Andyaka is right. Splitting it up is not practical and causes discrepencies. A single analog input is the only way to measure -10V to +10V in a smooth way. A simple circuit is often more accurate. The more components you add, the more dependencies you create. Use either a op-amp or three resistors to map the voltage.

Comment: I appreciate all the help guys. I am going to give the resistor voltage divider to op amp a try . Even with the arduino nano being as cheap as it is, the op amp should provide a little more security against an over-voltage condition caused by a faulty supply.