# Resistor value calculations for measure negative and positive voltages using Arduino ADC

Tags: adc, resistance

In order to measure negative and positives voltages with Arduino I found this solution.

[image: resistors]

I need to understand how to calculate R1, R2 and R3 according to specifications below.

Specs are:

The impedance has to be < 10K according to arduino ADC specs.

VOutput min voltage 0v and max voltage 5v.

VMeasure voltage range goes from -25v to +25v

In the solution ground can be shared without problems.

---

I tried to simulate in LTspice after I chose some values, but I cannot get output values on a dc sweep.
It only gives me constant voltage in the output of R2 and R3.

Does anyone know the reason?

[image: screenshot from LTspice]

Comment: Where exactly did you find that circuit?

Comment: Hi Elliot. I found as a response in this question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266786/arduino-negative-voltage-reading-with-positive-ground

Comment: The procedure for determining the resistor values is part of that earlier posting, so this is a duplicate.

Comment: The problem is that in that response is not clearly explained some of the ecuations used for example the relation between R2 and R3

Comment: apply milman theorem

Comment: play around in a simulator until you find something giving you the right values. http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html is ready to go w/o an install and can answer your question quickly.

Comment: Can you show how far you've gotten and where you're stuck with R2 and R3? That solution is pretty much exactly what I'd write.

Comment: What i got are this equations only and I get stucked after: R1 (value) = R1 + R2 || R3, R1 + R2 < 10K, R2 = 5/25.R1 but I dont know how to get the calcs for R3 on the equations. Also other issue i have is this: after I calculate all relations between resistors and get the voltage over every one, how can I choose the current over each one in order to calculate resistor value??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the formula:

Vout = (Vin/R1 + 5V/R2 + 0/R3)*R1||R2||R3 (assuming R3 is grounded).

Source impedance is R1||R2||R3. Let's set that to 10K.

Now we want Vout = 0V when Vin = -25V  and Vout = 2.5V when Vin = 0V.

So 2.5 = (5/R2)*10K => R2 = 20K

0 = -25/R1 + 5/20K => R1 = 100K

Then R3 must be 25K for R1||R2||R3 = 10K

We could  easily scale these values down a bit to reduce the source impedance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQsmOp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Excellent response Spehro. Last question I have is can I use a voltage reference like Ref02 to give +5v to r2 and r3 or I have to use an LDO that has good current capabilities?? this question is because I dont know if the voltage reference will tolerate the current flowing in this kind of circuit. Hope you understand me.

Comment: There is no requirement to sink current in this case, so the choice of a reference will depend on the accuracy requirements. You should pick the same reference as your ADC is using. Adding a precise reference to offset the input when your ADC reference is the supply regulator will introduce new and interesting errors.

Comment: In the circuit I design Ref02 is conected to Aref of my arduino so I will use the same. Thanks so much for your detail and clearly response.

Comment: Using this 3 resistor values gives me a total paralell resitance of 6.25k. Using this value in parallel to 10k of arduino gives me 3.846 kohm so the final impedance value is between the limits arduino says.

Answer (score 0):

The node you are measuring in your simulation is the one between R2 and R3:

5 * 10k / (10k + 4k) = 3,5714285

It is a simple voltage divider connected to a fixed 5V voltage source.

Varying the other voltage source will change the current in or out V2 (which is ideal), but not the voltage across R2 and R3 connected in series.

Your simulation:

[image]

Is the same as this:

[image]